# Detection of only the number in regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have the following regex :

```
(?<!__num)10\b
```

and when I want to detect 10 from the following sentence

> can there be B110\ numbers and 10 numbers in this sentence

the following is returned

> can there be B1`10`\ numbers and `10` numbers in this sentence

but I do not want 10 to be detected inside 110, so I changed the regex to

```
[^\d+](?<!__num)10\b
```

In that case, the result returned with 10 preceding a space character.

I want only the number given in the regex to be identified.
For example, If I give 110 in place of 10 in the regex, I want 110 to be identified even if preceded by "B."
So how can I construct the regex?
Thank you.

Comment: Change `(?<!__num)10\b` to `(?<!__num)(?<!\d)10\b` (since it is python)

Comment: How about if you try \b10\b ? This will only match 10 exactly

Comment: There is a error in such case : 
sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Comment: Check it again. Edited.

Comment: PushpeshKumarRajwanshi If I do that B110 won't get detected. Thanks @revo it worked

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi this won't work for the case when OP wants to capture `110` in `B110` since the B doesn't match `\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!__num)(?<!\d)10(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y3t0Zq/1)

The first two negative lookbehinds will be executed at the same location in a string and `(?<!__num)` will make sure there is no `__num` immediately before the current location and `(?<!\d)` will make sure there is no digit.

The `(?!\d)` negative lookahead will make sure there is no digit immediately after the current location (after a given number).

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Hzrz5I):

```
import re
# val = "110" # => <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(14, 17), match='110'>
val = "10"
s = "can there be B110 numbers and 10 numbers in this sentence"
print(re.search(r'(?<!__num)(?<!\d){}(?!\d)'.format(val), s))
# => <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(30, 32), match='10'>
```